# Interview question about virtual functions in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

I was asked this crazy question.
I was out of my wits.

Can a method in base class which is declared as virtual be called using the base class pointer which is pointing to a derived class object?

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to obtain one of the introductory books from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @James:  I think he is asking if you can call `base::foo()` not `derived::foo()` using `p` if `p` is a `base*` and points to a `derived`

Comment: @John: So? James is right, nevertheless.

Comment: I would have asked the interviewer. Why would you want to do that as you are breaking the contract designed by the developer of the class hierarchy. If the original developer had wanted you to call the base class method he would have provided a non virtual method that performed the action.

Comment: @John:  Ok, interpreting the question that way, it's slightly more interesting.

Comment: @sbi:  I could be wrong, but calling the base class' implementation of a virtual function seemed not all that basic to me.  James is right, of course, I'm just saying this is level 201 stuff, rather than level 101 stuff.

Comment: @John: Well, maybe you're right. IIRC, my introduction was Stroustrup's TCPL, 2nd edition, and it certainly covered things like this. Koenig/Moo might not mention it, though.

Comment: Even if you supplied the question "as asked", a simple code snippet might help clarify what was being asked.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you're trying to invoke a virtual method from the base class pointer, yes.

That's polymorphism.

If you're asking, with a base class pointer to a derived class, can you invoke a base class method that is overriden by the derived class? Yes that's also possible by explicitly scoping the base class name:

`basePtr->BaseClass::myMethod();`

Comment: Polymorphism is where it class the derived class method because the method is virtual in the base class. Actually calling the base class method via a pointer to base even if the base class method has been overridden is bypassing polymorphism which is different.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite.  The question is asking to call the base class's virtual method when the object is of the derived type which overrides the method.

Comment: Hrm, the question as written was confusing.

Comment: Hmm, I never knew this was an option (guess I never needed it). Thanks!

Comment: The question wasn't very clear, but the answer made the question clear.

Comment: @Alan. Good option. It was not known to me also. thanks for info.

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
class A            { virtual void foo(); }
class B : public A { virtual void foo(); }

A *b = new B();
b->A::foo ();
```

Comment: Actually I think it should be "A *b = new B()", instead of "B *b = new B()", to follow the question.

Answer (score 10):

You mean something like this. (Where `pBase` is of type pointer-to-base but the pointed-to object is actually of type `Derived` which is derived from `Base`.)

```
pBase->Base::method();
```

Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 10):

Yes -- you have to specify the full name though:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base { 
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Base"; }
};

struct derived : base {
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Derived"; }
};

int main() { 
    base *b = new derived;
    b->base::print();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, you have

```
class B 
{
public: 
    virtual void foo();
};

class D: public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
}

B* b = new D;
```

And the question is, can you call `B::foo()`. The answer is yes, using

```
b->B::foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class B 
{
public: 
    virtual void foo();
};

class D: public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
}

B* b = new D;
```

Try calling

```
(*b).foo()
```

to invoke base class foo function

Comment: are you sure that this will call base class foo function?
did you test it?

Comment: It was my general assumption that (*b) will eventually have proper object but on compile and run I found that this is not the case. It still calls derived function.

This has created confusion for me also that what is the difference between

(*b).foo()
and
B b1 = *b;
b1.foo()

Answer (score 0):

```
class B { 
    public: virtual void foo(); 
};

class D: public B { 
    public: virtual void foo() 
    { 
        B::foo();
    }; 
}

B* b = new D;
```

Solutions :

1. `b->foo();`
2. `b->B::foo()`
3. OR do not override/define foo() in the derived class D and call b->foo()
4. `B objb = *b;  objb.foo() ; // this is object slicing and not (*b).foo() as in one of the previous answers`

Answer (score -1):

No. Not in a clean way. But yes. You have to do some pointer manipulation, obtain a pointer to the vtable and make a call. but that is not exactly a pointer to base class, but some smart pointer manipulation. Another approach is using scope resolution operator on base class.

Comment: C++ does support directly what the question asks.  `base->base::function()` would do the trick.  No need to vtable hackery here.

Comment: Re-read your post.  "scope resolution operator" is not "another approach."  It is the only approach you should be considering.